# iOS FullScreen AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, camera, avcapturesession

I am developing a realtime video processing app for iOS 5. The video stream dimensions need to match the screen size of the device. I currently only have a iPhone 4 to develop against. For the iPhone 4 I set the AVCaptureSession preset to AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [AVCaptureSession new];
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
```

The captured images (via CMSampleBufferRef) have the size of the screen.

My question: Is the assumption correct that the images captured with a session preset of AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium have the full screen device dimensions on iPhone 4s and iPad2 as well? I unfortunately cannot verify that myself.

I looked at the apple documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Video_Input_Presets

but I cannot find a ipad2 dimension preset of 1024/768 and would like to save me the performance penalty of resizing images in real time.

Whats the recommended path to go?

Comment: Why do you want the screen size? You're wrong that it's the screen size on iPhone 4 anyway. The aspect ratio that comes out of the camera is different to the screen on an iPhone so it's never going to be the same.

Comment: you are correct, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of the camera and the resolution of the screen aren't really related anymore. You say

> The captured images (via CMSampleBufferRef) have the size of the
>   screen

but I don't think this is actually true (and it may vary by device). A medium capture on an iPad  2 and an iPhone 4s is 480x360. Note this isn't even the same aspect ratio as the screen on a phone or iPod: the camera is 4x3 but the screen is 3x2.

Comment: So far an ipad2 I am getting AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 and scale it down to fit into the user interface?

Comment: If you really want something that's the same size as the screen then that would be your best bet, yes. But remember that's actually too small as you need 1024x768 and the 720 is smaller than both dimensions of the screen.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve and I'm not up to date on what the current set of possible captures is. 1280x720 is a wide screen aspect ration (16x9) so you're either going to have to crop,  letterbox, or distort the image, in addition to downsampling it. But if you want max resolution and that's the closest resolution that's greater than or equal to the iPad, it might be the right choice. The cameras on the iPad 2 are no great shakes. I'd probably try a few resolutions and see if the higher resolutions are giving you any increase in quality.

Comment: @mattjgalloway makes a good point: I forgot that even 720 isn't enough on an iPad.

Comment: Upscaling from 720 pixel width to 768pixel width is perfectly fine for me. T